# WI-Fi extender and static IP issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, wireless-router

I have a WI-Fi router with some devices configured with static IP. I just added an extender (Netgear WN3000RP) and I see devices randomly jump from the main router to the extender. Now, when connected to the main router, they preserve the static IP but when under the extender, it assigns them a dynamic IP. 
It is possible to exclude access to the extender for some devices (based on MAC address) or it is possible to force the extender to assign the static configured IP?

**Update**
Extender manual says nothing about this:
https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WN3000RP/WN3000RP_IG_13APR2012.pdf

Comment: @Spiff no, I'm here because after searching google for a few days and trying to configure my extender I have not found the way to do it. So I think that, at last, I can try to ask someone that knows better about networking. You are free to ignore my question if you feel disturbed by it. Or just answer with "Yes, normally it is possible, check the manual"!

Comment: I updated my question